# creating a RedisClient from a typed akka behavior

Tags: scala, redis, akka, akka-typed

Im trying to use this scala redis library [etaty](https://github.com/etaty/rediscala) which needs an implicit `akka.actor.ActorSystem` when creating it's RedisClient object. I used the `context.system.classicSystem` in the Behaviors.setup method to provide the needed implicit.

Here is my code

```
 
def apply(): Behavior[Command] = Behaviors.setup { context =>
    implicit val system  = context.system
    implicit val classic  = context.system.classicSystem

   lazy val redis  = RedisClient(
      host = host,
      port = port
    )
```

However, I getting this errors in my logs.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: cannot create top-level actor [RedisClient-$a] from the outside on ActorSystem with custom user guardian
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.actorOf(ActorSystem.scala:895)
    at redis.RedisClientActorLike.<init>(Redis.scala:41)
    at redis.RedisClient.<init>(Redis.scala:86)
    at ng.logicbud.deidara.core.db.redis.RedisDbService$.redis$lzycompute$1(RedisDbService.scala:34)
    at ng.logicbud.deidara.core.db.redis.RedisDbService$.redis$1(RedisDbService.scala:34)
    at ng.logicbud.deidara.core.db.redis.RedisDbService$.$anonfun$apply$2(RedisDbService.scala:62)
    at akka.actor.typed.internal.BehaviorImpl$ReceiveMessageBehavior.receive(BehaviorImpl.scala:152)
    at akka.actor.typed.Behavior$.interpret(Behavior.scala:274)
    at akka.actor.typed.Behavior$.interpretMessage(Behavior.scala:230)
    at akka.actor.typed.internal.adapter.ActorAdapter.handleMessage(ActorAdapter.scala:129)
    at akka.actor.typed.internal.adapter.ActorAdapter.aroundReceive(ActorAdapter.scala:106)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:577)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:547)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:270)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:231)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:243)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
```

Comment: AFAIC in the documentation of the lib (https://github.com/etaty/rediscala) they instantiate an untyped/classic implicit like this: `implicit val akkaSystem = akka.actor.ActorSystem()` have you tried that?

Comment: Yes, i did. I have updated the question with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the redis client wants to create a top level actor under /user which is not possible with a typed actor system because there the /user actor is yours and the only one who is allowed to spawn children of that actor is itself.

The etaty library should be updated to not require doing that (for example return an actor for you to start, or use `systemActorOf` to start its own internal actors). You can however work around this by using a classic actor system in your app, and adapting to the typed APIs instead.